# Unable to Submit storm topology

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am trying to submit a Storm topology on a remote host using Eclipse.

Here is my code:

```
Config conf = new Config();
conf.setDebug(false);
conf.setNumWorkers(1);
conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_HOST, "hostName");
conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_THRIFT_PORT,6627);
conf.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS,Arrays.asList(new String[]{"hostName"}));
conf.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_PORT,2181);

// Remote submission
StormSubmitter.submitTopology("classMain", conf, topology);
```

But I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift7.TApplicationException: Binary field exceeded string size limit
  at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyAs(StormSubmitter.java:250)
 at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:271)
  at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:157)
  at com.rbc.rbccm.hackathon.Countersearch.submitTopology(Countersearch.java:111)
  at com.rbc.rbccm.hackathon.Countersearch.main(Countersearch.java:37)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift7.TApplicationException: Binary field exceeded string size limit
  at org.apache.thrift7.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
  at org.apache.thrift7.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:71)
  at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.recv_submitTopology(Nimbus.java:184)
  at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.submitTopology(Nimbus.java:168)
  at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyAs(StormSubmitter.java:236)
... 4 more
```

is there a string size limit on the parameters that we can pass to the submitTopology function?

When I follow the trail a bit more, it leads to:

```
public void submitTopology(String name, String uploadedJarLocation, String jsonConf, StormTopology topology) throws AlreadyAliveException, InvalidTopologyException, AuthorizationException, org.apache.thrift.TException
{
    send_submitTopology(name, uploadedJarLocation, jsonConf, topology);
    recv_submitTopology();
}
```

The `recv` is causing the issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: How long is the absolute pathname of the jar file?

Comment: "C:\\adasd\\sdsd\\workspace\\adasdasdsadsad\\target\\sample-mainClass-0.0.1.jar"

is that too long?

Comment: What happens when you attempt to use the command line client for uploading your jar to the Storm topology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase `nimbus.thrift.max_buffer_size` parameter. You can either set it in `storm.yaml` or in `Config` object.

Comment: Thanks Matthias, but since max_buffer_size is now deprecated (https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.0/javadocs/org/apache/storm/Config.html#NIMBUS_THRIFT_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE), how can the problem be solved now? I ran into the same error.

Comment: The problem is your very larger jar file. Storm 1.0 introduces a distributed cache https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.0/distcache-blobstore.html I never tried it, but you should be able to upload your jar file there (instead of transferring it via Nimbus.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the code in Storm's source code at `StormSubmitter.java`, it's this:

```
public static void submitTopology(String name, Map stormConf, StormTopology topology)
        throws AlreadyAliveException, InvalidTopologyException, AuthorizationException {
    submitTopology(name, stormConf, topology, null, null);
}
```

The Thrift error is because either the `name` you specified is too long (more than 2MB?) or `stormConf` has too much of info or there's the more likely cause, which is that when the `topology` is created, you're filling the Spout or Bolt instance with too much info.

In my case, I was creating a bolt into which I was initializing too much data.

```
builder.setBolt(genBolt, new GenBolt(myTable1.getHashMap(), myTable2.getHashMap(), myTable3.getHashMap(), myTable4.getHashMap()), 2)
  .fieldsGrouping(iterSpout, new Fields(con.BATCH_ID))
```